# Amazon Linux AMI - My EC2 instance can yum but cannot curl or ping

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I'm writing and ansible playbook and using cloudformation module to launch an EC2 instance (Amazon Linux AMI). 
Then I can ssh to that instance and from that instance I can install with yum but cannot curl or ping.

Ex: `$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
     curl: (7) Failed to connect to getcomposer.org port 443: Connection timed out`

Is there anyone can help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might missed the route specifics in route table. Please provide necessary route configurations for further assistance.

Comment: That's right. I have wrong route specifics in route table. I corrected it and it works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem. Here is what I did:

- Launched a new `t2.nano` instance using the default Amazon Linux AMI
- Connected via SSH
- `sudo yum install php`
- `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`

Result:

```
Composer (version 1.4.2) successfully installed to: /home/ec2-user/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
```

Comment: This is my error. I'm setting the instance within VPC but I set wrong Route Table, so this is the cause of problem.
Anyway. Thanks for your quickly response! @John Rotenstein.

Comment: Feel free to delete the Question if it will not assist other people.